# ZSH not sourcing zprofile

Tags: profile, zsh

I'm running zsh 5.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.  It seems that `~/.zprofile` isn't sourced at login nor new terminal.  `~/.zshrc` is sourced however.

I am running `oh-my-zsh`.

Any ideas on why this is or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`~/.zprofile` is only sourced when `zsh` is run as login shell, e.g. when logging in on the console or via SSH.

It will not be sourced by `zsh` when opening a new terminal or starting a new `zsh` session from within a running session. Anything you need in all interactive sessions, should be set in `~/.zshrc`. Anything you need in *all* `zsh` sessions, including scripts, should be set in `~/.zshenv`.

You can find additional information in the `zshall` manpage and on [this site](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/).

`~/.zshprofile` will (usually) also not be parsed by any other tools. So any environment variables set in `~/.zprofile` will usually not be available in an X11 session. If you need some environment variable to be available globally in your session, you might want to have a look at `man pam_env`.

Comment: What if login operation is done via ssh authorized key, zsh will still detected as login shell?

Comment: @alper that depends on the login shell set for the user in the system and has nothing to do with the ssh connection

Comment: debian 12 . ~/.config/zsh/.zprofile is sourced when opening alacrity with zsh as the shell.

Comment: @RichieHH Unfortunately I don't have a Debian at hand to dig into this, but at least the manpage provided with the `zsh-common` package on Debian still states that `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile` is only read for login shells. There might something else going: `alacritty` might explicitly call zsh as login shell (`zsh -l`). Alternatively, `~/.config/zsh/.zprofile` might be sourced by some other like `~/.zshenv` or `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`. Are you perchance using some pre-made configuration like  https://github.com/getantidote/zdotdir/ (which explicitly loads `.zprofile` from `.zshenv` for non-login shells)?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found out that while `~/.zprofile` seems to be ignored, `~/.profile` still gets sourced.
Not sure why this is the case, but simply moving things from `.zprofile` to `.profile` solved the problem for me...

Comment: Same for me on MacOS 14.0